# MySQL use leftjoin with select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

i have two tables:

```
1. movie
id, userid, movie_id, status, score
```

```
2. movie_data
id, name_de, name_en, description, url
```

When i use this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `movie` LEFT JOIN 
      movie_data ON movie.movie_id = movie_data.id 
ORDER BY movie.id
```

When i enter this query, i get all fields, but also two times id. But i don't manage to show only the first "id" or rename the second id. i hope someone can help me :)
Thanks for reading

Comment: You have `id` and `movie_id`... why not using `movie_id` as primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enumerate the columns in the `SELECT` clause and use aliases to disambiguate homonym columns:

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.user_id,
    m.movie_id,
    m.status,
    m.score,
    d.id data_id,   --> column alias
    d.name_de,
    d.name_en,
    d.description,
    d.url
FROM movie m 
LEFT JOIN movie_data d ON m.movie_id = d.id 
ORDER BY m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly list the columns you want.  Don't use `select *`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.userid, m.movie_id, m.status, m.score,
       md.name_de, md.name_en, md.description, md.url
FROM `movie` m LEFT JOIN 
     movie_data md
     ON m.movie_id = md.id
ORDER BY m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do, for example

```
SELECT 
    `movie`.*, -- select all fields from one table
     movie_data.id as movieId  -- and some fields of another table
FROM `movie` LEFT JOIN 
      movie_data ON movie.movie_id = movie_data.id 
ORDER BY movie.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The query should be next:

```
SELECT 
    `movie`.`id`,
    `movie`.`userid`,
    `movie`.`movie_id`,
    `movie`.`status`,
    `movie`.`score`,
    `movie_data`.`name_de`,
    `movie_data`.`name_en`,
    `movie_data`.`description`,
    `movie_data`.`url`
FROM `movie` 
LEFT JOIN `movie_data` ON `movie`.`movie_id` = `movie_data`.`id` 
ORDER BY `movie`.`id`;
```

This way you can exactly select what you need